# How do I convert one CRS (Coordinate Reference System) value into another using OSGeo4W Shell?

Tags: gis, coordinate-transformation, osgeo

I have QGIS 2.18 (latest version) installed for windows (new users). Along came OSGeo4W Shell. Now using this shell, I want to convert a specific value in one CRS into another. For example, if I know coordinates in WGS84 (say, 91.7362, 26.1445 just to give an example), I would like to know how to convert it to Indian 1954/UTM Zone 46N (which are in meters) using OSGeoShell.

PS: I know there is a way because I once successfully found the way. I had copied the syntax of the command but I deleted the file by mistake and I can't find the way in net again even after long time searches. It was barely a 2 line and simple command.

Comment: What are the commands that you've tried but does not work? Add some code to your issue

Comment: I don't remember the command anymore (that's the problem). Just that 1st line contained the command with source and target CRS while second line contained the value in source CRS. The result would be value in target CRS.

Comment: Also, I did not try random/wrong commands that did not work. The command was correct and worked which is why I want to know the command again

Answer (score 0):

I think, the command is:

```
osgeo4w
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:XXXX < input.csv > output.txt
```

Where the EPSG codes are the codes for the CRS (4326 is for WGS84). You have to find out the epsg code for your target crs and then you can perform the transformation.

Comment: I found it (in qgistutorials.com), in OSGeo4W : echo -72.42 21.1 | cs2cs +init=EPSG:4326 +to +init=EPSG:3857    to convert -72.42 degrees West of Prime Meridian, 21.1 degrees North from 4326 to 3857 and so on